# Install npm package globally that has peer dependency (not mentioned in package.json)

Tags: npm, dependencies, global, package.json, install.packages

I am trying to install [marktext](https://github.com/marktext/marktext) globally using npm (after cloning the repository):

```
npm install -g
```

`npm WARN dagre-d3-renderer@0.5.8 requires a peer of d3@^4.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.`

How should I install, the peer dependency for the global package? Please give the command so that it is safe and prevents future conflicts.

---

I did `npm install -g  d3@^4.13.0` but I still get the same error.

Is this a good idea to install the dependency globally? Also, do I need to lock this at the version globally to prevent auto update when I do global update?

Comment: I have the same exact question, just over different packages. Were you able to find an answer?

Comment: @Kamafeather  no

Answer (score 0):

Try it with upgrading `npm` to version 7

```
npm install -g npm@7
```

*npm 7* comes with new features. One of them is the automatically installing *peer dependencies*.

> Automatically installing peer dependencies: prior to npm 7 developers needed to manage and install their own peer dependencies. The new peer dependency algorithm ensures that a validly matching peer dependency is found at or above the peer-dependent’s location in the node_modules tree.